# Git history report

Tags: git

I'm trying to build the history report based on git log. But I'd like to skip branches except master even if they are merged. For example, I've create branch to work with feature X. There were a lot of small commits in this branch and I don't like to see these small steps in report. But when I'll merge this branch into master with message "Feature X implemented", I'd like to see this milestone in report. Thanks for helping git newbie.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to merge a branch without merging in the entire commit history for that branch, you can use the `--squash` command to `merge`.  This will apply all the changes from that branch to your working directory without actually creating any commits; at this point, you can generate a single commit for the entire history.  So if you have  `master` branch that looks like this:

```
commit 69b2303df9884627ade245fff4a3376f39646cbd
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@seas.harvard.edu>
Date:   Mon May 14 13:24:56 2012 -0400

    commit on master

commit c8496d9ac4048a414faffb91486075ab0952e2d7
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@seas.harvard.edu>
Date:   Mon May 14 13:24:43 2012 -0400

    initial commit
```

And another branch `newbranch` that looks like this:

```
commit 71587063a73368ea160a78cd6d130f828cb05e0e
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@seas.harvard.edu>
Date:   Mon May 14 13:25:36 2012 -0400

    commit 3 on new branch

commit 37ab4fc91c796ed05ecae0c8f504f263cee9603d
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@seas.harvard.edu>
Date:   Mon May 14 13:25:36 2012 -0400

    commit 2 on new branch

commit 5fd0768e355d1cba0905aaed327fb20ef263d6ef
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@seas.harvard.edu>
Date:   Mon May 14 13:25:36 2012 -0400

    commit 1 on new branch

commit 69b2303df9884627ade245fff4a3376f39646cbd
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@seas.harvard.edu>
Date:   Mon May 14 13:24:56 2012 -0400

    commit on master

commit c8496d9ac4048a414faffb91486075ab0952e2d7
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@seas.harvard.edu>
Date:   Mon May 14 13:24:43 2012 -0400

    initial commit
```

Then you can do this:

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash newbranch
git commit -m "merged changes from newbranch"
```

Then the log for the `master` branch will look like:

```
commit 0737d3dac5f769f837d4d0ce90ba1004c79d6a92
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@seas.harvard.edu>
Date:   Mon May 14 13:26:29 2012 -0400

    merged newbranch into master

commit 69b2303df9884627ade245fff4a3376f39646cbd
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@seas.harvard.edu>
Date:   Mon May 14 13:24:56 2012 -0400

    commit on master

commit c8496d9ac4048a414faffb91486075ab0952e2d7
Author: Lars Kellogg-Stedman <lars@seas.harvard.edu>
Date:   Mon May 14 13:24:43 2012 -0400

    initial commit
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Definitely good idea only one step from excellence. I can't get right now, how do determine, which branches were already merged and where were they merged in master.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, what you're looking for is essentially a list of merges into master.

If that's correct, then I believe this will work:

```
git checkout master
git log --merges
```

Comment: Thank you. The only problem is that this way it ignores commits thoes originally were in master. But If i will change a strategy and every milestone will require a merge, then it will works for me.